# How to change url without changing page in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a modal that has route of its own and I have an event listener that changes it's route after closing

```
    'closeTask' : function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Backbone.history.navigate( '#groups/' + this.model.get( 'LicenseId' ) + '/tasks' );
    },
```

but when I use this, there are times when closing the modal it reloads the page.

I also tried using

```
    'closeTask' : function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        App.navigate( '#groups/' + this.model.get( 'LicenseId' ) + '/tasks', { trigger:false } );
    },
```

but also gives me the same result. What should I use so that I can change my route without reloading the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, using `replace : true` solved my problem.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#groups/' + this.model.get( 'LicenseId' ) + '/tasks', { replace : true } );
```

read there documentation and this actually makes a lot of sense

> To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history,
>   set the replace option to true.

Answer (score 2):

This should modify the URL without triggering routing.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#groups/' + this.model.get( 'LicenseId' ) + '/tasks', false);
```

Add `false` as the second argument to `Backbone.history.navigate`.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate

Comment: When using Backbone.history.navigate the default for the second parameter is already false. Also tried this before but it did not work.